# Fine-uploader - Scaling picture by height

Tags: height, scaling, fine-uploader

I read the documentation about scaling with Fine Uploader:
http://docs.fineuploader.com/features/scaling.html

Is possible to scale a picture just considering the height of a picture?

For example we need to resize a picture in order that will be not taller than 1080 px.
If a picture dimensions are 1200x800, I want the it will be NOT scaled because the height is already less than 1080 px.
But with a picture that is 800x1200 I want that will be scaled based on the height of 1080 px.

Is it possible?

I'm not seeing anything in the API in order to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate a scaled version of an image on-demand with varying restrictions programmatically via Fine Uploader's [scaleImage API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#scaleImage).  This will generate a `Blob`, which you can pass to the [`addBlobs` API method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addBlobs).

If this proves to be cumbersome for your use case, and would like to see the ability to dynamically change scaling options per-file for internally scaled imags, please open up an [issue in Fine Uploader's issue tracker](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues).

Comment: From the `scaleImage` documentation, there is the `maxSize` option, but using that cannot limit just the height. If `customRisizer` is used, there is a `resizeInfo.height`, is that what should be used? If so, what is the syntax (is it just simply `customResizer: !qq.ios() && function (resizeInfo) {resizeInfo.height = 240; .... }`?